# "All my visits" or "all of my visits"?

Tags: word-usage

> All (of) my visits to the house were solitary.

Do I need that *of*? Why or why not? (Or maybe they are both acceptable?)

Comment: You are right and the "of" is optional ... but that's a needlessly complicated sentence.  "I always went to that house by myself" is simple and clear.

Answer (score 1):

All my visits.

All of my visits.

Yes, both are grammatical.

You can say either "all my visits" or "all of my visits", without any difference in meaning.

The word "all" as determiner can be used in the structure "all + possessive pronoun + plural noun" or "all of + possessive pronoun + plural noun".

Comment: I remember Swan Grammar saying that "of" is more formal and has a slight stress on the "all" word.